# Generalization of permanent definition based on number of permutation cycles

Tags: co.combinatorics

Let $A$ be an $n$ by $n$ matrix and $x$ a free parameter. Define
$$p(A,x)=\sum_{\pi \in S_n} x^{n(\pi)}A_{1\pi(1)}\ldots A_{n\pi(n)},$$
where $\pi$ ranges over the permutation group $S_n$ and $n(\pi)$ is the number of cycles in the cycle decomposition of $\pi$. Clearly, $p(A,1)=perm(A)$, the permanent. In general, $p(A,x)$ has properties in common with the permanent such as $p(PAQ,x)=p(A,x)$ for permutation matrices $P,Q$.

Is this a well-known structure in combinatorics and where might I find more information?

Answer (score 9):

The collection of [immanants](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immanant_of_a_matrix)

$$Imm_\lambda(A) = \sum_{\pi \in S_m} \chi_\lambda(\pi) A_{i\pi(1)}...A_{n\pi(n)}$$

generalized the permanent and determinant and your $p(A,x)$, since we can write $x^{n(\pi)}$ as a linear combination of characters.

Comment: Continuing Doug's answer, when we write $x^{n(\pi)}$ as a linear combination of irreducible characters $\chi^\lambda$, then the coefficient of $\chi^\lambda$ is $\prod_u (x+c(u))/h(u)$, where $u$ runs over all squares in the diagram of $\lambda$, $c(u)$ is the content of $u$, and $h(u)$ is the hook length of $u$.

Answer (score 4):

This exact version of a "generalized permanent" is called $\beta$-extension in [this](http://link.aip.org/link/?SJDMEC/1/425/1) Foata-Zeilberger paper (see also [my paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0607737) for the algebraic context and further non-commutative generalizations, Cartier-Foata style).

Answer (score 0):

There are some papers on this topic from the point of view of rook theory by [V. S. Shevelev](https://www.math.bgu.ac.il/%7Eshevelev/).